# Calling a custom COM interface from a ATL project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, com, atl

How do I call a COM interface from an ATL project?

I was following the example at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/comintro.aspx but they use the IActiveDesktop class which is defined in wininet.h. How do I call a custom component where I do not have the interface definition. How do i generate it?

In a MFC project I can generate a MFC class from a TypeLib. But what do I have to do to generate my header from a TypeLib in an ATL project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are wanting to call a third-party COM component, you do not need to interface definition file (.idl) for that component. Use the CComPtr ATL class, which encapsulates the typical things that use do with any COM object, such as CoCreateInstance and QueryInterface. there is also a template specialization for IDispatch that makes using CComPtr with ActiveX controls particularly easy.

```
CComPtr p;
static CLSID id = { 0xcf9904f7, 0x8623, 0x465b, { 0xa0, 0x5e, 0x9d, 0x5a, 0xa, 0x2c, 0x1a, 0xe7 } }; 
p.CoCreateInstance(id);
```

Comment: It will be beneficial to able to invoke function through interface, instead of routed through IDispatch.

Comment: Could you give a small example? For QueryInterface I have to have a GUID and the Interface definition. Where do I get the Interfache definition for my third party dll?

Comment: @Jan: You don't need the interface definition per se, you just need the documentation for the interface, so you can know what methods are available on the interface. Make sure your component is properly registered in the machine registry.

Comment: @Thomas: Thanks. I understand that you suggest i.e. the use of the IDispatch Interface via CComPtr<IDispatch> p; and then p.Invoke(...).

Comment: Can't I generate a header file containing the right class defs? The TypeLib Viewer of OleView has an option to save the Idl as a Header File. But doing so i do not get a new file. Do you know why?

Comment: @Jan: Yes, can call invoke that way. Note the default template is the IDispatch specialization, so declaring CComPtr p; is equivalant to declaring CComPtr<IDispatch> p;.  For IDispatch, there are also some handy methods like GetPropertyByName.

Comment: @Jan: Are you wanting to call through IDispatch or do you want to make vtable calls without IDispatch?

Comment: @Thomas: I need a call through IDispatch like you explained it to me.

Comment: @Thomas: I thought that there is a way to have a generated class definition of my third party module, like in the codeproject example, where they use IShellLink.

Comment: @Jan: I see what you're asking now. That Code Project example is not actually a ATL project. It uses the native C++ COM APIs. ATL is a huge object oriented framework that is build around those APIs. No matter. There are two baic ways to call a COM object. You can either use IDispatch.Invoke, or you can directly use the interface pointer that you obtain from CoCreateInstance (sometimes you can use both). In the later case, yes you do need a header that defines the methods on the interface. The header is not actually an idl, the header is usually generated from the idl.

Comment: If you don't have the header or the idl, then you must use IDispatch. Many third-party activex controls are setup to use IDispatch and don't supply a C++ header file. In fact, most controls are never called from C++ at all.